# Compile Delphi 2010 project with MSBuild w/o RAD Studio Command Prompt

Tags: delphi, msbuild

i am trying to compile a delphi 2010 project with msbuild, without using the RAD Studio Command Prompt.
Therefore i created a batch file, setting the environment variables(the ones from rsvars.bat and the user overrides) and then using this command:

```
msbuild projectNameHere.dproj
```

giving me the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets(136,3): error MSB6003: The specified task executable could not be run. The filename or extension is too long.

any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: Impossible to say. What you describe works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

IIUYC you copied the contents of rsvars.bat into your batch. Instead just [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) rsvars.bat in your batch before the msbuild line. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say from your description, but its possible that your absolute path is greater than 260 characters. Its also possible that your temp folder is full and the build system cannot create the temp files it needs. Check your absolute path length and clean your temp folder.